# saveFileDialog How to save to user input?

Tags: c#

I have added this to my class file

```
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Process.Start(url);
    }
```

But when the process starts, it automatically downloads the file and puts it on my desktop. How can I make it so that it downloads to the user input in the saveFileDialog1?

Comment: What do you mean by *to the user input in the saveFileDialog1*?

Comment: @awhitehouse104 When the dialog box opens, I want the file to save where the user picks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.Net.WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.DownloadFile(url, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            web.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: This method works, but it also returns a 403 forbidden. Can I make this stop?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using Process.Start(), you can use the WebClient class by which you can download files and say the location where to save and the name of that file....